# How to move an element by attribute value to the last sibling position with xsl?

Tags: xslt

I need to move (not copy) an element with a given value in attribute id to the last position of its siblings, e.g. `//ul/li[@id='b']`:

Input:

```
<ul>
    <li id="a">a</li>
    <li id="b">b</li>
    <li id="c">c</li>
    <li id="d">d</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Output:

```xml
<ul>
    <li id="a">a</li>
    <li id="c">c</li>
    <li id="d">d</li>
    ...
    <li id="b">b</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "*an element with a given value*" Given how?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I mean with value "b" as an example

Comment: Yes, but how will this value be "given"? Will you be passing it as a parameter to the stylesheet at runtime, or what?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I mean 'given' as 'specified or stated'. Synonyms: 'particular', 'specific'

Comment: **1.** Please don't be rude. **2.** The value 'b' does not appear in your input. The processor can only work with the given input. Therefore the question where will the value b' come from is the natural question to ask here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Please accept my apologies. I didn't intended to offend anybody. The value 'b' is simply an example of a value of the attribute 'id'. As far as this example is concerned it doesn't matter what attribute/value you use. What I needed has been answered by others. Namely `element[@attribute!='value']` vs. `element[@attribute='value']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input XML is as simple as that in the question, you can use this:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="ul">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="li[@id != 'b']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="li[@id = 'b']"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted. Your answer came first thus the check.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="id" select="string('b')"/>
    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <xsl:element name="ul">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="li[@id!=$id]"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="li[@id=$id]"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted.